# MySQL is crashing with the error "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My website crashes at random times because of a problem with MySQL and I can't quite pinpoint it. For one, the crash itself happens very seldom (perhaps once a month) so I can't replicate it. Because of that, I don't know what exactly is causing the issue.

When I first built our site many years ago, I was using mysql_ calls to connect to the database. I learned the error of my ways and started using PDO. Unfortunately, there is a LOT of code that used the mysql_ calls and I haven't gotten around to replacing every single one of them yet. So, my site has a mix between PDO and mysql_ calls.

When the site connects to the database, it first calls mysql_connect() and then connects to PDO through a wrapper.

The error I'm receiving comes into play when I use `mysql_connect()`. I've dug through logs and I can't find a specific cause for the error. As soon as it happens, it crashes the MySQL server and therefore the website. I can't even assume that mysql_ is the problem because it crashes before it even gets to the PDO wrapper. It might just be a MySQL connection issue.

I've done some searching and it looks like some others have recommended revising `bind-address` in my.cnf, which I've done.

I've also gone through the website and tried to remove as many mysql_ calls as possible.

Here's some example logfile output, with some info redacted:

```
Error connecting to database. Reason: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111

[Mon Jun 09 13:01:29 2014] [error] [client ****] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in database.php on line 89
[Mon Jun 09 13:01:29 2014] [error] [client ****] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setErrorCallbackFunction() on a non-object in database.php on line $
[Mon Jun 09 13:01:29 2014] [error] [client ****] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in database.php on line 89
[Mon Jun 09 13:01:29 2014] [error] [client ****] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setErrorCallbackFunction() on a non-object in database.php on lin$
[Mon Jun 09 13:01:29 2014] [error] [client ****] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0 in $
[Mon Jun 09 13:01:29 2014] [error] [client ****] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in database.php on line 89
[Mon Jun 09 13:01:29 2014] [error] [client ****] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setErrorCallbackFunction() on a non-object in database.php on line $
[Mon Jun 09 13:01:29 2014] [error] [client ****] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in database.php on line 89
[Mon Jun 09 13:01:29 2014] [error] [client ****] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setErrorCallbackFunction() on a non-object in database.php on lin$
[Mon Jun 09 13:01:29 2014] [error] [client ****] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0 in $
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

***If the MySQL server crashes***, then this issue is caused by the MySQL daemon itself and not your client code.

It can't be the database (schema) either, as you don't get to this point. (the DB is selected after succesful connection )

Make sure that:

- MySQL binaries are the latest version or at least the latest version that ships via your distribution package management (same for all libs used by MySQL)
- the RAM in your server is sound, maybe run a memcheck
- the harddisk in your server is sound, maybe run smart utils or a full disk scan